# Linked List vs. Trees on the Heap

Tags: c++, linked-list, tree, binary-tree, dynamic-memory-allocation

I am told that linked lists must be implemented on the heap, but trees can be implemented on the stack? The case the the tree is implemented on the stack is one where there is no removal. If we were to implement the trees with removal, would we need to implement in on the heap?

I'm only familiar with dynamic memory in C++ (not sure if this gives any context to my question).

Comment: ***I am told that linked lists must be implemented on the heap*** That is not exactly true but usually the way it is implemented. You could create a large fixed size global array or local / stack array and create a linked list inside of that. Same goes for a tree.

Comment: This question talks about implementing a linked list inside an array: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665607/how-do-you-implement-a-linked-list-within-an-array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7665607/how-do-you-implement-a-linked-list-within-an-array)

Comment: Maybe someone downvoted because they think you did not do enough research or because ***linked lists must be implemented on the heap*** is not correct. I am unsure I did not downvote.

Comment: ***The case the the tree is implemented on the stack is one where there is no removal*** This is also not correct. You can create a linked list or a tree on the stack and you can add or remove nodes in such an implementation. However there will be a maximum number of nodes that can be added as you can't allocate more than the fixed sized array that you created to implement the stack based container.

Comment: What I mean from add and remove nodes is that the nodes can be added or removed from the linked structure. However physically in memory you have preallocated a fixed number of nodes and that does not change with an on the stack list or tree.